# O Analytics para Firebase é integrado com o google analytics?

Tags: firebase

Gostaria de saber se o Analytics para Firebase é integrado com o google analytics, pois não gostaria que a equipe de marketing acesse o firebase para visualizar o analytics.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O Firebase Analytics é o mesmo que Google Analytics. Eles só pegaram o produto já existente e incluíram no Firebase. Infelizmente, não tem uma consola separada para que outras equipes vejam os registos feitos.